# Random bsods and freezes on new hdd

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze, bsod

I recently got a new HDD, installed Windows 7 64 bit, and after usage I noticed some issues. I was getting random BSoDs, with error code 0x24 and 0x3b. Sometimes Windows hangs and freezes for some reason and I was hearing very light sounds from the HDD.

Here is what I tried:
I tested the HDD many times, no issues.

I tested the ram, no problems.

I even tested the cpu, no issue at all.

I scanned for corrupted files and found none.

Comment: Are you able to return the drive for a replacement? That seems like the first thing to do here.

Comment: What do you mean the drive is fresh and no errors or issues were found

Comment: Noises like you have indicate a hardware error of some kind. Freezing and BSOD are also consistent with a hardware error. A fresh install of Windows 7 should work fine.

Comment: i literaly checked for missing files even reinstalled, and same issue

Comment: Run a short and long S.M.A.R.T test on the drive to rule it out via [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage). First review drive info: `smartctl -a /dev/<drive>` → Run a short test and review: `smartctl -t short && timeout -t 61 && smartctl -a /dev/<drive>` → Finally run a long test, which will take hours: `smartctl -t long /dev/<drive>` _(periodically check progress via `smartctl -a /dev/<drive> | findstr "progress"`)_ → Once the long test completes, review: `smartctl -a /dev/<drive>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a faulty SATA cable that is connected between the hard drive and the motherboard. I had the same issues, one time my Windows froze which left me with no choice but to reboot. After I rebooted I got a grub error (because I have Linux installed):

> attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0

Also, I was hearing weird sounds from the HDD, so I shut down, unplugged the SATA cable and re-plugged it. The issue was gone, but it appeared again so I replaced the SATA cable and the issue was never seen again.

Comment: unplugging and replugging the sata cable really helped me, so i need to order a new one, thank you so much!!!